# Makefile rule to copy sources from many folders

Tags: makefile

I have a large collection of Makefiles that produce XML files in a whole collection of directories. I'd like to write a "client" Makefile that picks some of the end products, and copies only the ones that have been modified. I can make a rule per file easily enough, but I'm not seeing how to use a pattern rule given that the folder for each source file is different. I'd much rather only have to pop a source file into a list and have everything else just work. Something like:

```
SOURCE_DIR = somedir
TARGET_DIR = otherdir
SOURCES = \
        $(SOURCE_DIR)/dir1/file1.xml \
        $(SOURCE_DIR)/dir2/file2.xml \
        $(SOURCE_DIR)/dir3/file3.xml \
        $(SOURCE_DIR)/dir4/file4.xml
TARGETS = $(patsubst %,$(TARGET_DIR)/%,$(addsuffix xml,$(basename $(SOURCES))))

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGET_DIR)/%.xml: $(???)/%.xml:
        cp $< $@
```

I can't figure out what to put in $(???).

**Edit:** Added example as per comments

Here's an example of what I've got in mind:

```
SOURCE_DIR = /project/Data
TARGET_DIR = src/XML
SOURCES = \
        $(SOURCE_DIR)/Airports/airports.xml \
        $(SOURCE_DIR)/Product/ISIC/isic.xml \
        $(SOURCE_DIR)/PortSources/ports.xml \
        $(SOURCE_DIR)/Commodity/htscodes.xml
```

And the targets would end up resolving to:

- src/XML/airports.xml
- src/XML/isic.xml
- src/XML/ports.xml
- src/XML/htscodes.xml

so, for example, if `/project/Data/Product/ISIC/isic.xml` is more recent than `src/XML/isic.xml` and `/project/Data/Product/Commodity/htscodes.xml` is more recent than `src/XML/htscodes.xml`, then the output from `make` should be:

```
cp /project/Data/Product/ISIC/isic.xml src/XML/isic.xml
cp /project/Data/Commodity/htscodes.xml src/XML/htscodes.xml
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're removing the .xml suffix then adding it back again.  But since you're trying to replicate the directory structure (from what I can tell... it would be simpler if you showed an explicit example of the desired source and target pathname--for example an example of a "correct" invocation of `cp`) can't you just use `SOURCE_DIR` for `???`?

Comment: I'm not intending to, but I don't know a way to tell $(basename) to only remove the directories without also stripping the suffix.

Comment: Well, `basename` _doesn't_ remove the directories.  That's why I was saying in my comment that you're replicating directory structure.  From the example in the GNU make manual, `$(basename src/foo.c)` expands to `src/foo`.  If you really wanted it to expand to `foo.c` you should use `notdir`, not `basename`.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid copying stuff needlessly, how about using `rsync` instead of `cp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now that I see your example it's more clear what you want: the way you were creating `TARGETS` was not right for what you want to do.  As in my comment above, you want `notdir` for this.

You can do what you want with [VPATH](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Search.html), like this:

```
SOURCE_DIR = /project/Data
TARGET_DIR = src/XML
SOURCES = \
    $(SOURCE_DIR)/Airports/airports.xml \
    $(SOURCE_DIR)/Product/ISIC/isic.xml \
    $(SOURCE_DIR)/PortSources/ports.xml \
    $(SOURCE_DIR)/Commodity/htscodes.xml

vpath %.xml $(sort $(dir $(SOURCES)))

TARGETS = $(addprefix $(TARGET_DIR)/,$(notdir $(SOURCES)))

all: $(TARGETS)
.PHONY: all

$(TARGET_DIR)/%.xml : %.xml
        cp $< $@
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. Not sure why, but after amending the Makefile, I'm now getting "make: *** No rule to make target `src/XML/ports.xml', needed by `all'.  Stop."

Comment: That means it can't find a `ports.xml` on the vpath directories.  You'll have to use `$(info $(sort $(dirname $(SOURCES))))` to see the list of directories and make sure they're correct, and maybe run make with `-d` debug on (this will give a lot of output).  This solution assumes that these files already exist before make is started.  You can't use vpath if the SOURCES files themselves have to be generated from some other target.

Comment: Ah, it's supposed to be $(dir, not $(dirname. It's working fine now. It won't let me edit your post because the difference is less than six characters. :-/

Comment: Oops.  Fixed.  Sorry.